# Android Studio - Android Device Monitor - Empty View

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms

I am trying to use the Android Device Monitor within Android Studio, but somehow I managed to remove all views.

I have tried resetting the perspectives, Window->Show View->(Any View), and even re-installing Android Studio but nothing shows up.

[image: Android Device Monitor]

Does anyone know how to reset the Device Monitor back to it's default views? (With the devices on the left, and the heap/threads/allocation views on the right.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've experienced this same problem by using **Window -> Reset Perspective**. One should expect this to *fix* this issue, not break it. Go figure.

In any case, the DDMS workspace preferences are stored in `%USERPROFILE%\.android\monitor-workspace` (e.g. `C:\Users\my_user\.android\monitor-workspace`).

Just delete that folder and you're good to go.

Comment: @matiash : Worked for me too.. Thanx..!!

Comment: Today sucked until I found you. Thank you.

Comment: @matiash thanks a ton ...I was breaking my head to solve this issue for so many days.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you'll need to enable 'show hidden files' in the finder if you are on a mac. Then, the workspace directory is in users/your_username/.android/monitor-workspace.

See http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/ for how to show hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:

1. Go to `C:\users\my_user\.android\monitor-workspace)`
2. Close android device monitor
3. Delete all files/folders inside of monitor-workspace folder
4. Run android device monitor again

Where "my_user" is your user folder.

Comment: could you provide a screen shot and elaborate more ?  "close android device monitor delete into monitor-workspace run android device monitor again" is ambiguous with respect to just a directory path

Comment: @NiallJG - this answer appears to be saying that you can delete everything in that "monitor-workspace" folder (once you find it).  (Or you can follow the earlier answers, and delete the folder itself.)  Steps 2 and 4 explain that you need to close android device monitor before deleting (otherwise it will re-save the unwanted layout, recreating that folder and files).  Then re-run the monitor after deleting.

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot looks like you are running Windows. So, you could go to `C:\Users\user3106174\` and delete the directory named `.android` (or something similar).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I choose the other answer as deleting just that one folder is necessary.

Comment: how to get that folder path in  ubuntu

Comment: @SrishtiRoy it should be in your home directory, but hidden .android