# Android Studio Ubuntu - Android Device Monitor - Empty View

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms

I am trying to use the Android Device Monitor within Android Studio in Ubuntu, somehow I managed to remove all views.

I have tried resetting the perspectives, Window->Show View->(Any View), and even re-installing Android Studio but nothing shows up.

In one of the earlier SO post, there was a solution shared, now i am trying to find the corresponding Ubuntu file location corresponding to the file shared earlier in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723585/android-studio-android-device-monitor-empty-view).

Can some body help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now i am trying to find the corresponding Ubuntu file location corresponding to the file shared earlier in this post.

That would be `~/.android/monitor-workspace/`.

In general, the `.android` directory will be in `~` on OS X and Linux, and in `%USERPROFILE%\` (e.g., `C:\Users\my_user\`) on Windows.

Comment: Do you know what is the exact path, i cant find any thing even close to the above one

Comment: @Shiv: "Do you know what is the exact path" -- that is the exact path.

Comment: This is the exact path in Ubuntu Home\.android\monitor-workspace. Hope this helps some one

Comment: @Shiv: That is not a path in Ubuntu. "Home" is not a the name of some directory. It is the name of a "place" in the Nautilus file browser that you are presumably using. In the actual Linux filesystem, what Nautilus shows as "Home" maps to the shorthand of `~/`, which in turn maps to a directory under `/home/` tied to your user ID (e.g., `home/shiv/`). Please take the time to learn the operating system that you are using for development.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, 'you are right, the full path is /home/(username)/.android

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this. In Ubuntu, these are hidden files, so you need to use Ctrl + H to view them. After deleting the files from the below path, my device monitor is back.

```
home/my_user/.android/monitor-workspace
```

Comment: which folder i need to delete .android or moniotr-workspace?